# Retrieving XML node names

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to retrieve the names of all the nodes from XML file using "node.getNodeName()". While doing so, every node name is preceeded and followed by "#text". Because of that, i am not getting the exact count of nodes as well. I want "#text" to be eliminated while retrieving the names. How do i do that??

Comment: You'd better tag this question with "java" if you want a quicker feedback ;)

Comment: I used SAXBuilder.. it worked as i wanted..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With that :

```
package com.hum;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

/**
 *
 * @author herve
 */
public class PrintNameXML
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String xml = "<a><o><u>ok</u></o></a>";
    Document doc = 
     DocumentBuilderFactory
     .newInstance()
     .newDocumentBuilder()
     .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println("name is : "+nl.item(i).getNodeName());
    }
  }
}
```

I get :

```
name is : a
name is : o
name is : u
```

Is that you search ?